# How to force the user to enter multiple values into an array and capping the number

Tags: java, arrays

I'm brand new to java and learning arrays, so I apologize for the sure incorrect terminology in my question title, but how would I go about forcing the user to enter more than one value in an array, but also not allowing them to enter more than, say 90?

Comment: Maybe something like a [`do-while` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html), using something like a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html) to read the user input

Comment: But could you bring some code, because what is the datatype of the array or is the input from a Scanner or hardcoding?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you looking [do while example](http://ideone.com/rdW6Zj)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [] Ages = new int[90]; // Set the size of the array
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int counter = 0;

        do {
            try 
            {
                int number = scan.nextInt(); // Scan the number
                Ages[ counter ] = number; // Storage in the array
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Only numbers are allowed"); // only allows number
                counter--;
            }
            counter++;
        } while ( counter <= 89 ); // you need you enter 90 number
    }
}
```

I hope this could answer your question.